# Changing histograms in pyplot's subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I am comparing histograms of images in python. Thats when I noticed that the histogram of the same image, plotted twice with pyplot's **subplots** can look different depending on the subplots index. Here a minimal example:

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize = (15,15))
img1 = blocks_1[0][0]
img2 = blocks_1[0][0]
ax0[0].imshow(img1)
ax1[0].imshow(img2)
hist3, bins3 = np.histogram(img1, bins=255)
hist4, bins4 = np.histogram(img2, bins=255)
ax0[1].bar(bins3[:-1], hist3)
ax1[1].bar(bins4[:-1], hist4)
```

The two histograms in my jupyter notebook look different if I plot them like this:

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize = (10,10))

img1 = blocks_1[0][0]
img2 = blocks_1[0][0]
ax0[0].imshow(img1)
ax0[1].imshow(img2)
hist3, bins3 = np.histogram(img1, bins=255)
hist4, bins4 = np.histogram(img2, bins=255)
ax1[0].bar(bins3[:-1], hist3)
ax1[1].bar(bins4[:-1], hist4)
```

How can this happen? Here an image which show the different histograms. They are not even mirrored.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have an idea how your data (i.e. `blocks_1`) looks like as I cannot reproduce the error with random data

Comment: @T.Kau well I assumed thats obvious from the added picture. It's just a grayscale image 100x100. Both upper plot show this image. I just left the cmap="gray" away... 
If you d like to recreate the situation, just use the same image 2 times.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem seems to lie with `plt.bar()`. It even shows up if you try to plot the same histogram twice (i.e. `ax1[0].bar(bins3[:-1], hist3)
ax1[1].bar(bins3[:-1], hist3)`. That seems to be a bug on the side of pyplot?! As a workaround you could simply use `plt.hist` instead of `np.histogram` and `plt.bar`

Comment: Ou I see. Thank you very much. I guess I'll open an issue.

Comment: I already opened one ;)

Comment: :P damn, too slow. By the way, if this is really a bug make it an answer. I'd accept it.

Comment: I marked as duplicate of similar issues where the answers are more constructive than the one given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now as an answer:

This seems to be a bug on the part of matplotlib as this problem also arises when plotting the same data twice. I opened an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13909).

A workaround would be to use `plt.hist(img1, bins=255)` and so on.